# How can I group elements in HTML while printing query results?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with different types of food:

```
id     name       type
1      apple      1
2      orange     1
3      lettuce    2
4      broccoli   2
5      pork       3
```

Then in my PHP file I have an array with a number code for each type of food, like this:

```
$foodTypes = array (
    1 => 'FRUITS',
    2 => 'VEGETABLES',
    3 => 'MEAT'
);
```

What I want is to select my whole food table and print it in HTML with the food type as the title, like this:

```
FRUITS:
apple
orange

VEGETABLES:
lettuce
broccoli

MEAT:
pork
```

I know how to do this with multiple queries, one for each food type, but I'd like to do this with one single query. How can I do this?

Comment: do you know how to loop through the results?

Comment: Sure. I just don't see how to print the food category only once for each food group.

Comment: well loop through.. populate a your three types as three different arrays that hold the correct data... then the title would be like `<h1>MEAT:</h1> <br> <span> meat array results </span>` or whatever html you want to use

Comment: Select your db rows, ordered by the type. Then save them in an array with the key being the type, ie. `$foods[$row['type']] = $row['name']`. Then you can loop through your `$foodTypes` with a sub loop through `$foods`, using the `$foodTypes` key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to do this with what you already have.  First, select from your foods table ordered by type.

```
SELECT id, name, type FROM foods ORDER BY type;
```

Then loop through the results, adding a heading each time the type changes.

```
$type = null;                                // No type initially
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($row['type'] !== $type) {            // Check if type has changed
        $type = $row['type'];                // Reset type to the new type
        echo $foodTypes[$type] . ":<br/>";   // Print header
    }
    echo $row['name'] . "<br/>";
}
```

Obviously the html here is pretty simple, but I assume you have a more specific idea for how you want to format it.

Comment: You are right. I can do that with what I already have, I just didn't know how to print it correctly in php. Thanks for the simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

You do this:

```
SELECT name, type from [table] group by type
```

That will do your select and group.  To name them, you add a case statement:

```
SELECT id, name, 
     CASE type 
         WHEN 1 
           THEN 'Fruits'
         WHEN 2 
           THEN 'Vegetables'
         WHEN 3 
           THEN 'Meats'
     END AS 'type' 
FROM [table] 
ORDER BY type
```

In addition, you can use your array rather than hardcoding the case results by replace it with `$foodtypes[0]` and so on.

This will take care of grouping.  I think I may have misunderstood.  If you need this to paint out each, it probably should look more like this:  (noticed I dropped the GROUP BY and changed it to ORDER BY)

**html**

```
<table>
<tr><td>id</td><td>name</td><td>type</td>
```

**php**

```
    $result = $mysqli->query($stmt);

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        print '<tr><td>'. $row['id'] .'</td><td>'. $row['name'] .'</td><td>'. $row'type'] .'</td></tr>';

}
```

**end php**

**close html**

```
</table>
```

That should be everything you need.

Comment: Can you explain to me how would I print this in html using the php "while"? Because as far as I can see here, the GROUP BY is getting only one row of each type instead of all of them...

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest adding an additional table to your database for your types

```
id   type
1    FRUITS
2    VEGETABLES
3    MEAT
```

Then your database draw would be

```
SELECT
    t1.name,
    t2.type
FROM tblFood AS t1
INNER JOIN tblTypes AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.type
```

On the PHP side:

```
$result = array();
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $result[$row['type']][] = $row['name'];
}
```

Then echo the HTML:

```
foreach($result as $type=>$list) {
    echo "<h1>".htmlspecialchars($type)."</h1>";
    foreach($list as $food) {
        echo "<p>".htmlspecialchars($food)."</p>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding another table is a good idea, but I think that overall, this method of querying and joining overcomplicates things for me a bit... but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Perhaps, but I tend to look at the future simplicity.  Joining on a table allows you to add more types without changing your code, and if you're ambitious, gives you the ability to add types from the app itself.  The more dynamic your data is, the more versatile your app becomes.  Also, the versatility of PHP's array keying cannot be understated.

Answer (score 1):

what i was saying before is something like this...

**SETUP:**

```
  $foodTypes = array (
    1=> 'FRUITS',
    2=> 'VEGETABLES',
    3=> 'MEAT'
  );
  $rows = array(
    1 => array('name'=> 'apple', 'type' => 1),
    2 => array('name'=> 'orange', 'type' => 1),
    3 => array('name'=> 'lettuce', 'type' => 2),
    4 => array('name'=> 'broccoli', 'type' => 2),
    5 => array('name'=> 'pork', 'type' => 3)
  );
```

i just made $rows with the data but you could easily do that with a sql select and then just

`array_push ($rows, $row)`

**LOOP:**

```
foreach ($foodTypes as $fud_key => $temp){
echo "<h1>" .$temp. "</h1>";
echo "<br>";
foreach($rows as $key => $value){ 
  if($value['type'] == $fud_key){
     echo "<span>" . $value['name'] . "</span>";
     echo "<br>";
    }; 
  };
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

## FRUITS

apple

orange

## VEGETABLES

lettuce

broccoli

## MEAT

pork